# How can I aggregate a dataframe on specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a `pandas` dataframe `df` like this, say

```
ID activity date
1  A        4
1  B        8
1  A        12
1  C        12
2  B        9
2  A        10
3  A        3
3  D        4
```

and I would like to return a table that counts the number of occurence of some `activity` in a precise list, say `l = [A, B]` in this case, then

```
ID activity(count)_A  activity(count)_B
1  2                  1
2  1                  2
3  1                  0
```

is what I need.

What is the quickest way to perform that ? ideally without `for` loop

Thanks !

Edit: I know there is `pivot` function to do this kind of job. But in my case I have much more `activity` types than what I really need to count in the list `l`. Is it still optimal to use `pivot` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) as first step and then pivoting - fastest should be [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and last [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), the best test each solution with real data:

```
df2 = (df[df['activity'].isin(['A','B'])]
         .groupby(['ID','activity'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .add_prefix('activity(count)_')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df2)
   ID  activity(count)_A  activity(count)_B
0   1                  2                  1
1   2                  1                  1
2   3                  1                  0
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['activity'].isin(['A','B'])]

df2 = (pd.crosstab(df1['ID'], df1['activity'])
        .add_prefix('activity(count)_')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df[df['activity'].isin(['A','B'])]
          .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='activity', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
          .add_prefix('activity(count)_')
          .reset_index()
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `df.groupby('activity').size().reset_index(name='count')`
should do as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate by `Counter` and use `pd.DataFrame` default constructor

```
from collections import Counter

agg_= df.groupby(df.index).ID.agg(Counter).tolist()
ndf = pd.DataFrame(agg_)

    A   B   C   D
0   2   1.0 1.0 NaN
1   1   1.0 NaN NaN
2   1   NaN NaN 1.0
```

If you have `l = ['A', 'B']`, just filter

```
ndf[l]

    A   B   
0   2   1.0 
1   1   1.0 
2   1   NaN
```